# How to swap the lower left keys on osx?

Tags: macos

I'd like to swap the right cmd key for the left fn key as I'm used to cmd=ctrl in Windows. I'd also like to swap the other control keys for the command key as it's more natural to use the pinky for command and control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need I little tool: [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25141/keyremap4macbook)

Everything is explained here: https://moox.io/blog/switch-ctrl-fn-keys-macbook-keyboard/